# How do I execute both an update query and an insert query in one connection

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to read data from a form and update one table while adding media to a different table but the connection closes as soon as I execute the update query. How do I keep it open and run the insert query for the second table?

```
 try
        {
            dbConn.Open();
            OleDbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd1, dbConn);
            OleDbAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@buttonClicked", OleDbType.Integer).Value = archiveIdNumber.InnerText.Substring(33);
            OleDbAdapter.Fill(infoDs, "First Table");
            OleDbAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = cmd2;
            OleDbAdapter.Fill(infoDs, "Second Table");
            OleDbAdapter.Dispose();

            string cmdString = "Update ARCHIVE_DECADE_TBL Set PRODUCT_NAME='" + Request.Form["nameBox"] + "', MODEL_NUMBER='" + Request.Form["modelBox"] + "', YEAR_INTRODUCED='" + Request.Form["startBox"] + "', YEAR_DISCONTINUED='" + Request.Form["endBox"] + "', PRODUCT_LINE='" + Request.Form["lineBox"] + "', LOCATION='" + Request.Form["locationBox"] + "', QUANTITY='" + Request.Form["quantityBox"] + "' " +
                "Where ARCHIVE_ID_NUMBER=" + int.Parse(Request.Form["archiveBox"]);

            OleDbAdapter.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand(cmdString, dbConn);

            OleDbAdapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (addPhotos.HasFiles)
            {
                //cmdString = "Update ARCHIVE_DECADE_TBL Set PRODUCT_NAME='" + Request.Form["nameBox"] + "', MODEL_NUMBER='" + Request.Form["modelBox"] + "', YEAR_INTRODUCED='" + Request.Form["startBox"] + "', YEAR_DISCONTINUED='" + Request.Form["endBox"] + "', PRODUCT_LINE='" + Request.Form["lineBox"] + "', LOCATION='" + Request.Form["locationBox"] + "' " +
                //"Where ARCHIVE_ID_NUMBER=" + int.Parse(Request.Form["archiveBox"]);
                var x = 0;
                if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("includes/images/archives/" + Request.Form["archiveBox"] + "_1")))
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("includes/images/archives/" + Request.Form["archiveBox"] + "_1"));
                }

                String filePath = Server.MapPath("includes/images/archives/" + Request.Form["archiveBox"] + "_1");
                HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = Request.Files;

                for (int i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.Count; i++)
                {
                    HttpPostedFile userPostedFile = uploadedFiles[i];
                    if (userPostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        string extension = Path.GetExtension(userPostedFile.FileName);
                        //Request.Form["archiveBox"] + "_" + i will be the same as the "IMAGE" column in the IMAGE_TBL
                        uploadedFiles[i].SaveAs(filePath + "/" + Request.Form["archiveBox"] + "_" + (i + 1) + extension);

                    }
                    x++;
                }


                cmdString = "INSERT INTO ARCHIVE_IMAGE_TBL (ARCHIVE_ID, MODEL_NUMBER, LOCATION, IMAGE, NUMBER_OF_IMAGES, IMAGE_FILE_TYPE) VALUES ('" + Request.Form["archiveBox"] + "', '" + Request.Form["modelBox"] + "', '" + Request.Form["locationBox"] + "', '" + Request.Form["archiveBox"] + "_1" + "', '" + uploadedFiles.Count + "', '.jpg');";

                OleDbAdapter.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand(cmdString, dbConn);

                OleDbAdapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            dbConn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: why don't you create a stored procedure to do this.. and if you do not want to do that, then at least change your existing code to use `Parameterized query` also break the functionality into 2 separate methods it's not that difficult to accomplish what you are trying to do

Comment: I apologize... I'm a newbie and am trying to teach myself so it's a little harder than it may seem to be for me

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using procedures:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [MeProcedure]
AS
BEGIN
--procedure content
END
```

Or you can just try connected query:

```
UPDATE tbl SET [a]=1, [b]='c' WHERE [d]=@param; INSERT INTO tbl_2( [a], [b] ) VALUES ( 3, 'g' ) WHERE [d]=@param;
```

This can be done with SqlCommand object like so:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE tbl SET [a]=1, [b]='c' WHERE [d]=@param; INSERT INTO tbl_2( [a], [b] ) VALUES ( 3, 'g' ) WHERE [d]=@param;");
cmd.Parameters["param"].Value = 5;
var result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

EDIT:
Example with query from question:

```
string cmdText = "Update ARCHIVE_DECADE_TBL Set PRODUCT_NAME=@pName, MODEL_NUMBER=@mNumber, YEAR_INTRODUCED=@yearInt, YEAR_DISCONTINUED=@yearDisc, PRODUCT_LINE=@pLine, LOCATION=@loc, QUANTITY=@quantity Where ARCHIVE_ID_NUMBER=@archive";
```

You can add another queries into this like:

```
cmdText += ";SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ARCHIVE_DECADE_TBL";
```

Then you can assign SqlCommand and it's parameters:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText,dbConn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("pName", DbType=DbType.VarChar, 12));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("archive", DbType=DbType.Integer){ Value = int.Parse(Request.Form["archiveBox"] });
// more parameters here
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Can you explain this a little more for me? What do I put in the brackets and what does setting the param to 5 do?

Comment: Every SqlCommand object has a list of 'named' Parameters that you can use without worries about SQL-Injection. Usage of those is very simple, when you create an SQL query like: "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE a=1" you can modify this tu use parameters like this: "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE a=@param". Next you can just add a parameter into your SQLCommand : cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("param")); [Remember to use the same name @param == param] then you can just set this parameter in the code and Sql execution will do the rest

Comment: Ok so in my case would [a] be equal to "PRODUCT_NAME" and [b] equal to "MODEL_NUMBER"? I'm just a little confused as to how your answer fits into my code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you call:

```
 OleDbAdapter.Dispose();
```

right after setting it up, I am surprised that this works at all.

Don't Dispose() of the object until you are completely finished with it.